# Gmail and the € symbol

Tags: gmail

I have a problem with Gmail (Google Apps): I can't send the symbol `€`, because after sending the email, Gmail rewrites it to text—“EURO”. What's wrong with Gmail? My other Gmail account (not on Google Apps) works fine.

[image: gmail]

Comment: I tried in both my personal and my work (G. Apps) accouts and they show the € symbol.

Comment: [If you have found a solution for your problem](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/GrBg-GP9eUY), please post it below and accept is as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure you are sending your message with UTF-8 encoding:

> **Send with UTF-8 encoding**
>
> Each time you send a message, Gmail automatically selects an
>   appropriate encoding for the language(s) in which you've composed your
>   mail. It's possible, however, that the recipient may not be able to
>   properly view the message you've sent.
>
> If your contacts are having trouble viewing messages you've sent them,
>   we recommend using 'UTF-8' (Unicode) for all outgoing mail. UTF-8 is a
>   standard encoding that's accepted by many email clients.
>
> Here's how to use UTF-8 encoding:
>
> - Click the **gear icon**  in the upper right, then select **Settings**.
> - Scroll down until you see the `Outgoing message encoding:` section
> - Select **Use Unicode (UTF-8) encoding for outgoing messages**

[Taken from this Google Help Page](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/22841?hl=en)